# printf() prints newline in wrong place

Tags: c, printf

I'm somewhat of a beginner in C so please excuse any crass mistakes!

I'm trying to print some formatted values with printf() but it starts a newline in the middle of the output even though there isn't a '\n'!
The problem is in function list_topic on line 442.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct
{
    int t_id;
    char t_name[35];
    char date_creation[30];
    char last_post_date[30];
    int sub_users;
    int num_posts;
    char t_desc[500];
} topic;

typedef struct
{
    int u_type;
    int t_maxreach;
    int u_sub_topic[15];
    char u_name[16];
    char u_pass[16];
} utilizador;

void instalar();
void menu_inicial();
void menu_admin();
void menu_topic();
void menu_user();
void login();
void options();
void topic_gest();
void user_gest();
void stats();
void new_topic();
void alt_topic();
void rmv_topic();
void list_topic();
void new_user();
void val_new_user();
void list_user();
void edit_user();
void erro();
void erro_app();
void erro_cred();

int main()
{
    struct stat st = { 0 };
    int n;

    if (stat("SUP", &st) == -1)                     //verifica se o diretório já existe 
    {
        instalar();                                   //chama a função instalar()
    }

    menu_inicial();                                 //chama a função menu_inicial()
    scanf("%d", &n);                                //lê a opção escolhida pelo utilizador

    while (n != 2)
    {
        switch (n)
        {
        case 1: {login(); break; }
        default: {erro(); }
        }

        menu_inicial();                               //chama a função menu_inicial()
        scanf("%d", &n);                              //lê a opção escolhida pelo utilizador

    }

    system("clear");
    return 0;
}

void instalar()                                   //cria o diretório base e o administrador padrão
{
    {
        system("clear");
        printf("O programa não está instalado. Deseja instalar? [s/n]\n");

        char t;                                                 //recebe input

        for (int s = 0; s == 0;)
        {
            scanf("%c", &t);
            getchar();

            if (t == 's')                                                   //se o input for 's' instala
            {
                system("clear");
                printf("A instalar...\n\n");

                mkdir("SUP", 0700);
                mkdir("SUP/Topicos/", 0700);

                FILE *ft = fopen("SUP/Topicos/topicos.dat", "wb");

                topic tbase;

                tbase.t_id = 1;

                strcpy(tbase.t_name, "Topico inicial");

                time_t curtime;
                time(&curtime);
                strcpy(tbase.date_creation, ctime(&curtime));
                strcpy(tbase.last_post_date, ctime(&curtime));

                tbase.sub_users = 0;
                tbase.num_posts = 0;

                strcpy(tbase.t_desc, "topic desc");

                fwrite(&tbase, sizeof(topic), 1, ft);
                fclose(ft);

                //testar
                topic input;
                ft = fopen("SUP/Topicos/topicos.dat", "rb");
                while (fread(&input, sizeof(topic), 1, ft))
                {
                    printf("id = %d \nname = %s \ntopic desc = %s \nlast post date = %s \nsubscribed users = %d \nnumber of posts = %d", input.t_id, input.t_name, input.t_desc, input.last_post_date, input.sub_users, input.num_posts);
                }
                getchar();

                FILE *f = fopen("SUP/utilizadores.dat", "wb");
                utilizador admin;
                admin.u_type = 1;
                admin.t_maxreach = 0;
                strcpy(admin.u_name, "admin");
                strcpy(admin.u_pass, "admin");
                admin.u_sub_topic[0] = tbase.t_id;
                fwrite(&admin, sizeof(utilizador), 1, f);
                fclose(f);

                printf("Pressione a tecla ENTER para continuar...");
                getchar();

                break;
            }
            else if (t == 'n')                                   //se o input for 'n' não instala e sai do programa
            {
                system("clear");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}

void menu_inicial()
{
    system("clear");

    printf("----------** Menu de registo **----------\n");
    printf("|                                       |\n");
    printf("|        1) Login / Autenticação        |\n");
    printf("|        2) Sair                        |\n");
    printf("|                                       |\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------\n");
}

void menu_admin()                               //menu depois do login
{
    system("clear");

    printf("------------------** Menu **-------------------\n");
    printf("|                                             |\n");
    printf("|            1) Gerir Tópicos                 |\n");
    printf("|            2) Gerir Utilizadores            |\n");
    printf("|            3) Estatísticas                  |\n");
    printf("|            4) Logout                        |\n");
    printf("|                                             |\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
}

void menu_topic()
{
    system("clear");

    printf("-------------------** Gestão de Tópicos **--------------------\n");
    printf("|                                                            |\n");
    printf("|              1) Criar novo tópico                          |\n");
    printf("|              2) Alterar atributos de um tópico             |\n");
    printf("|              3) Eliminar tópico                            |\n");
    printf("|              4) Listar tópicos                             |\n");
    printf("|              5) Voltar atrás                               |\n");
    printf("|                                                            |\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
}

void menu_user()
{
    system("clear");

    printf("---------------------** Gestão de Utilizadores **--------------------\n");
    printf("|                                                                   |\n");
    printf("|                1) Criar novo utilizador                           |\n");
    printf("|                2) Validar pedido de novo utilizador               |\n");
    printf("|                3) Listar utilizadores                             |\n");
    printf("|                4) Editar utilizadores                             |\n");
    printf("|                5) Voltar atrás                                    |\n");
    printf("|                                                                   |\n");
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
}

void login()                                                                     //processo de autenticação do utilizador
{
    system("clear");

    char name[16], *pass;
    int res;

    utilizador input;

    printf("----------** Login / Autenticação **----------\n");

    printf("Nome de utilizador: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    getchar();

    pass = getpass("Palavra-passe: ");

    FILE *f = fopen("SUP/utilizadores.dat", "rb");

    while (fread(&input, sizeof(utilizador), 1, f))                                  //testa se as credenciais são válidas e são de administrador
    {
        if (input.u_type == 1)
        {
            res = strcmp(name, input.u_name);
            res += strcmp(pass, input.u_pass);

            if (res == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (input.u_type == 0)
        {
            res = strcmp(name, input.u_name);
            res += strcmp(pass, input.u_pass);

            if (res == 0)
            {
                res = 2;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(f);

    switch (res)
    {
    case 0: {options(); break; }
    case 2: {erro_app(); break; }
    default: {erro_cred(); }
    }
}

void options()                                                    //escolha de opções depois do login
{
    int i;

    menu_admin();

    scanf("%d", &i);
    getchar();

    while (i != 4)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 1: {topic_gest(); break; }
        case 2: {user_gest(); break; }
        case 3: {stats(); break; }
        default: {erro(); }
        }

        menu_admin();
        scanf("%d", &i);
        getchar();
    }
}

void topic_gest()                                                          //escolher opções de gestão de tópicos
{
    int i;

    menu_topic();
    scanf("%d", &i);
    getchar();

    while (i != 5)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 1: {new_topic(); break; }
        case 2: {alt_topic(); break; }
        case 3: {rmv_topic(); break; }
        case 4: {list_topic(); break; }
        default: {erro(); }
        }

        menu_topic();
        scanf("%d", &i);
        getchar();
    }
}

void user_gest()                                                           //escolher opções de gestão de utilizadores
{
    int i;

    menu_user();
    scanf("%d", &i);
    getchar();

    while (i != 5)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 1: {new_user(); break; }
        case 2: {val_new_user(); break; }
        case 3: {list_user(); break; }
        case 4: {edit_user(); break; }
        default: {erro(); }
        }

        menu_user();
        scanf("%d", &i);
        getchar();
    }
}

void stats()                                                               //mostra as estatísticas dos tópicos e dos utilizadores
{

}

void new_topic()                                                           //cria um tópico novo
{
    system("clear");

    topic new, filein;

    FILE *f = fopen("SUP/Topicos/topicos.dat", "ab+");

    printf("---------------------** Criar Novo Tópico **--------------------\n\n");
    printf("Nome do tópico <máximo de 50 carateres>: ");
    fgets(new.t_name, 35, stdin);

    strcpy(new.t_name, strtok(new.t_name, "\n"));

    if (strlen(new.t_name) > 30)                                                                                      //testa se o nome inserido é demasiado comprido
    {
        system("clear");

        printf("O nome é demasiado comprido, por favor insira outro nome!\n\n");
        printf("Pressione a tecla ENTER para voltar atrás...");
        getchar();

        return;
    }
    else
    {
        while (fread(&filein, sizeof(topic), 1, f))
        {
            if (strcmp(filein.t_name, new.t_name) == 0)                                                                   //testa se o tópico inserido já existe
            {
                system("clear");

                printf("Este tópico já existe, por favor insira outro nome!\n\n");
                printf("Pressione a tecla ENTER para voltar atrás...");
                getchar();

                return;
            }
        }
    }

    rewind(f);

    new.t_id = 1;

    while (fread(&filein, sizeof(topic), 1, f))                                                                       //testa a id dos tópicos já registados para não terem ids duplicados
    {
        if (new.t_id <= filein.t_id)
        {
            new.t_id += 1;
            printf("id = %d", new.t_id);
            getchar();
        }
    }

    printf("Descrição do tópico <máximo de 500 carateres>: ");
    fgets(new.t_desc, 500, stdin);

    time_t curtime;

    time(&curtime);

    strcpy(new.date_creation, ctime(&curtime));
    strcpy(new.last_post_date, ctime(&curtime));

    new.sub_users = 0;
    new.num_posts = 0;

    fwrite(&new, sizeof(topic), 1, f);
    fclose(f);

    printf("Tópico '%s' criado com sucesso!\n\n", new.t_name);
    printf("Pressione a tecla ENTER para continuar...");
    getchar();

}

void alt_topic()
{
    system("clear");

    char name[30];

    printf("-------------------------** Alterar Tópico **------------------------\n\n");
    printf("Insira o nome do tópico que deseja alterar: ");
    fgets(name, 30, stdin);

    printf("name = %s", name);
    getchar();
}

void rmv_topic()
{

}

void list_topic()
{
    system("clear");

    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("| ID   | Nome                           | Descrição                                    | Criado em                     | Último post em                | Utilizadores subscritos | Nº de posts   |\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    FILE *ft = fopen("SUP/Topicos/topicos.dat", "rb");
    topic input;
    while (fread(&input, sizeof(topic), 1, ft))
    {
        printf("| %04d | %-30s | %-44s | %-25s | %-29s | %-23d | %-13d |\n", input.t_id, input.t_name, input.t_desc, input.date_creation, input.last_post_date, input.sub_users, input.num_posts);
        printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
    getchar();
}

void new_user()
{

}

void val_new_user()
{

}

void list_user()
{

}

void edit_user()
{

}

void erro()                                                                  //dá mensagem de erro na escolha da opção
{
    system("clear");

    printf("Opção desconhecida!\n\n");
    printf("Pressione a tecla ENTER para continuar...");
    getchar();
}

void erro_app()                                                            //dá mensagem de credenciais sem autorização e sai do programa
{
    system("clear");

    printf("As credenciais inseridas não são credenciais de administrador!\n");
    printf("Por favor use o programa CLIENTE para iniciar a sessão!\n\n");
    printf("Pressione a tecla ENTER para sair...");
    getchar();

    system("clear");
    exit(0);
}

void erro_cred()                                                          //dá mensagem de credenciais erradas e reinicia login()
{
    system("clear");

    printf("Nome de utilizador e/ou palavra-passe incorretos!\n\n");
    printf("Pressione a tecla ENTER para continuar...");
    getchar();
    getchar();

    login();
}
```

The output should be like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID   | Nome                           | Descrição                                    | Criado em                     | Último post em                | Utilizadores subscritos | Nº de posts   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0001 | Topico inicial                 | topic desc                                   | Tue May 15 12:36:03 2018      | Tue May 15 12:36:03 2018      | 0                       | 0             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But ends up like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID   | Nome                           | Descrição                                    | Criado em                     | Último post em                | Utilizadores subscritos | Nº de posts   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0001 | Topico inicial                 | topic desc                                   | Tue May 15 12:36:03 2018
 | Tue May 15 12:36:03 2018
     | 0                       | 0             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have no clue what could be wrong!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is a huge wall of code!

Comment: TLDR; Please post the *minimal* code that you think would reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, please minimize the code :) Off the top of my head, you fread() a block and then treat the field input.t_desc as a string. Without seeing your input file, who's to say that that field doesn't have a newline in it? If it does, then printing it will of course break the line. If you want output in your table, you might need to reformat this description field, or maybe change all newlines into spaces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue with your program is that `ctime` returns the time string with a `'\n'` at the end. You can see that the spurious new lines are always after printing the time.

You can remove that after copying it to the designated buffer.

For example after

```
strcpy(new.date_creation, ctime(&curtime));
```

You can add

```
new.date_creation[strlen(new.date_creation)-1] = '\0';
```

You need to add this to every string you are creating from `ctime` (or `asctime`, if you use that in future).

Actually, the existence of this `'\n'` is guaranteed by the C standard. You can look at the sections for [`ctime`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.3.2) and [`asctime`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.3.1).

Quoting `C11`, chapter [§7.27.3.1p2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.3.1p2)

> The `asctime` function converts the broken-down time in the structure pointed to by `timeptr` into a string in the form
>
> `Sun Sep 16 01:03:52 1973\n\0`

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't realise ctime returned the string with '\n' at the end! I'll be more careful from now on!